# Draggable is not working when parent gets hidden

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable

The following error just occurs in IE8.

Demo: http://tinyw.in/BLrg

Click on show at Newsletter 313. If you now hover over the blue bar at the left, a layer slides out containing some elements. You can drag each one of this elements. If you start dragging the layer slides back. As you see, in IE8, the dragged element also gets hidden or if you directly drag it over it might get added instantly. And that's the problem, you can open it in IE9, Firefox, Chrome and it works. To see, how it should actually work.

Here's the code which can be found in logic.frontend.js:
(Just a part which is actually used)

```
$( ".draggable li table" ).draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid',
    appendTo: 'body',
    start: function(ui) {
        $('#elementsContainer').hide('slide', {
             direction: "left"
        }, 500);   
}
});


var height = $('#elementsContainer').outerHeight();
$('#elementsContainerHandle').css('height', height);

$('#elementsContainerHandle').mouseenter(function() {
    $('#elementsContainer').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $('#elementsContainer').show('slide', { direction: "left" }, 500);
});

$('#elementsContainer').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
});

$('#elementsContainer').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

The problem is, that `#elementsContainer` gets hidden and due to that all it's children including the dragged element are getting hidden as well. In other browser, `.hide()` doesn't affect the dragged element because of the option `appendTo : 'body'`. But in IE8, this seems to break somehow although I'm quite sure the element gets added to the body. I've tried making the draggable visible again with css, `.show()` etc. but i didn't get it.

Thanks